# Coulombs Law: Protons atract each other

Tags: python, pygame, physics

I'am working on a simulation of the Coulomb's Law with pygame, but I have a problem. When I start the Simulation an set two Protons, they attract each other. But there is more!
When I set an electron and a proton, they both start to "travel" with a constant distance to each other in the same direction.

Here is my code:

```py
import pygame
import numpy as np
import math

pygame.init()

# window-settings
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 800
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
pygame.display.set_caption("Electric field simulation")

# constants
Pi = np.pi
epsilon0 = 8.85 * (10**(-12))
q = 1.6 * (10**-19)

# colors
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
BLUE = (100, 149, 237)
RED = (188, 39, 50)

class Charge:
    TIMESTEP = 50000

    def __init__(self, x, y, radius, color, q):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.color = color
        self.q = q

        self.x_vel = 0
        self.y_vel = 0

    def draw(self, win):
        pygame.draw.circle(win, self.color, (self.x, self.y), self.radius)

    def attraction(self, other):
        other_x, other_y = other.x, other.y
        distance_x = other_x - self.x
        distance_y = other_y - self.y
        distance = math.sqrt(distance_x ** 2 + distance_y ** 2)

        force = (1 / (4 * Pi * epsilon0)) * self.q * other.q / (distance ** 2)
        theta = math.atan2(distance_y, distance_x)
        force_x = math.cos(theta) * force
        force_y = math.sin(theta) * force
        return force_x, force_y

    def update_position(self, charges):
        total_fx = total_fy = 0
        for charge in charges:
            if self == charge:
                continue

            fx, fy = self.attraction(charge)
            total_fx += fx
            total_fy += fy

        self.x_vel += total_fx / self.q * self.TIMESTEP
        self.y_vel += total_fy / self.q * self.TIMESTEP

        self.x += self.x_vel * self.TIMESTEP
        self.y += self.y_vel * self.TIMESTEP


def main():
    run = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    proton = Charge(200, 200, 10, RED, q)

    electron = Charge(300, 200, 10, BLUE, -q)

    charges = [electron, proton]

    while run:
        clock.tick(60)
        WIN.fill(WHITE)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:  # To set charges
                if event.button == 1:  # Sets positive charge
                    charges.append(Charge(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1], 10, RED, q))

                if event.button == 3:  # Sets negitive charge
                    charges.append(Charge(pygame.mouse.get_pos()[0], pygame.mouse.get_pos()[1], 10, BLUE, -q))

        for charge in charges:
            charge.update_position(charges)
            charge.draw(WIN)

        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think the problem is the attraction-function, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Your `force` calculation already incorporates `q`, I find the division with it suspicious. Even if you want there `F=m*a`, and throw `q` in as mass, `q` has a sign, while mass has not.

Comment: the trigonometry part can be skipped with a simple division: `force_x=distance_x/distance*force`

Comment: And as masses of electrons and protons differ by orders of magnitude, you need to include the mass if you want your simulation to be a bit realistic.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Assuming that the math is understood, this problem seems to boil down to a simple logical error, and not a question about actually writing the code. Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I have not the possibility to run your code but have you mixed up the direction of your force?
At least [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) calculates `r1-r2`

Annother source of error might be the sin, cos etc. functions have you checked for your example that the calculated values are correct?

If I understand your code correct you update all positions one after eachother and apply the changes right away. Dependend on your application you might want to

1. Calculate all forces
2. Update all Values

Otherwise you have a multiple states of your system in just one time step.

Comment: Okay I changed the distance in that way, but the problem is the same just with the electrons instead of protons. I removed the trigonometric part, but it changed anything. And yes this is what I want to do, but how should I change the code?

Comment: You could store all calculated changes in a list and update them in second step. 
Maybe use a list of dicts to track the forces `[{'fx':fx, 'fy':fy}]` 
I think you have to caclulate all attractions and sum up the forces of all charges. If you know the total force calculate acceleration, velocity and position.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved the problem by calculating the direction of the force. With this I calculate at first the the force but return the absolute and then calculate the direction and speed.
Here is the code of my changes (I just changed something in the updating and attracting function):

```
    def attraction(self, other):
        other_x, other_y = other.x, other.y
        distance_x = self.x - other_x
        distance_y = self.y - other_y
        distance = math.sqrt(distance_x ** 2 + distance_y ** 2)
        if self.q != other.q and distance < 5:
            return 0,0

        force = (1 / (4 * Pi * epsilon0)) * self.q * other.q / (distance ** 2)
        force_x = distance_x / distance*np.abs(force)
        force_y = distance_y / distance*np.abs(force)

        return force_x, force_y

    def update_position(self, charges):
        total_fx = total_fy = 0
        for charge in charges:
            if self == charge:
                continue

            fx, fy = self.attraction(charge)
            total_fx += fx
            total_fy += fy

            self.x_vel += total_fx / self.q * self.TIMESTEP
            self.y_vel += total_fy / self.q * self.TIMESTEP

            if self != charge and self.q < 0 and self.q != charge.q:
                x = abs(self.x - charge.x)
                y =  abs(self.y - charge.y)
                self.direction = [x / np.sqrt((x ** 2) + (y ** 2)),y / np.sqrt((x ** 2) + (y ** 2))]

            elif self != charge and self.q > 0 and self.q != charge.q:
                x = abs(self.x - charge.x)
                y = abs(self.y - charge.y)
                self.direction = [-x / np.sqrt((x ** 2) + (y ** 2)), -y / np.sqrt((x ** 2) + (y ** 2))]

            elif self != charge and self.q < 0 and self.q == charge.q:
                x = abs(self.x - charge.x)
                y = abs(self.y - charge.y)
                self.direction = [-x / np.sqrt((x ** 2) + (y ** 2)), -y / np.sqrt((x ** 2) + (y ** 2))]

            elif self != charge and self.q > 0 and self.q == charge.q:
                x = abs(self.x - charge.x)
                y = abs(self.y - charge.y)
                self.direction = [x / np.sqrt((x ** 2) + (y ** 2)), y / np.sqrt((x ** 2) + (y ** 2))]

            self.x += self.x_vel * self.TIMESTEP * self.direction[0]
            self.y += self.y_vel * self.TIMESTEP * self.direction[1]
```

I know this code isn't that beautiful, but at first it works.